# Hadoop 2.2.0- RecoveryInProgressException while appending content to an existing file

Tags: hadoop, ipc, hdfs, hadoop2

I am not able to append content to an existing file in HDFS.Exception is thrown at the following line.

```
outputStream = hdfs.append(dirPath);
```

where dirPath is "hdfs://master:54310/test/Readme.txt".

Please note that,I am running Hadoop on single node for development.

The exception log is given below.

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.RecoveryInProgressException): Failed to close file /test/Readme.txt. Lease recovery is in progress. Try again later.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2310)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2153)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2386)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.appendFile(FSNamesystem.java:2347)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.append(NameNodeRpcServer.java:508)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.append(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:320)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java:59572)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2048)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2042)
```

Also note that at the same line, I sometime get this exception

```
failed to create file /test/Readme.txt for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_187487992_15 on client 127.0.0.1 because current leaseholder is trying to recreate file
```

Could anyone please elaborate as to why these exceptions are thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the dfs.replication is set to 1 in hdfs-site.xml,the replication value will still be set to 3(Please suggest as to why this happens,restarted couple of times).I had to set the value of  replication to 1 to make it work ,from the code using,

```
  hdfs.setReplication(dirPath, (short) 1);
```